# What is <context-group> in xliff

Tags: xml, xliff

I noticed that upon generating an xliff file, it created nodes named `context-group`. I'm not sure what they are used for.

```
     <trans-unit id="edc96753971323c438706da1820e74730a79d1af" datatype="html">
        <source>Your response to this survey has already been recorded. Thank You.</source>
        <context-group purpose="location">
          <context context-type="sourcefile">app\core\forbidden.component.ts</context>
          <context context-type="linenumber">5</context>
        </context-group>
        <note priority="1" from="description">Message for survey already taken</note>
        <note priority="1" from="meaning">Survey Already Taken Page</note>
      </trans-unit>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<context-group>` element holds context elements relating to the level in the tree in which it occurs. Thus context can be set at a `<group>` level, a `<trans-unit>` level, or a `<alt-trans>` level. Each `<context-group>` element may be named, allowing different uses for each group. When the `<context-group>` is named, these uses can be controlled through the use of XML processing instructions. Because the `<context-group>` element may occur at a very high level, a default context can be established for all `<trans-unit>` elements within a file. This default can be overridden at many subsequent levels. The optional name attribute may uniquely identify the `<context-group>` within the `<file>` element. The optional crc attribute allows a verification of the data. The optional purpose attribute indicates to what use this context information is used; e.g. "match" indicates the context information is for memory lookups.

For more info, see: http://docs.oasis-open.org/xliff/v1.2/os/xliff-core.html#context-group

Comment: What can be the practical use of this node? Btw, thanks for the answer.

Comment: you can kind of think of it has meta-data that provides additional information about mapping and references. you can see more usages here: http://docs.oasis-open.org/xliff/v1.2/xliff-profile-po/xliff-profile-po-1.2-cd02.html